# find the values a, b for the next series to converge and for the series to diverge

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Determine for what values of a and b the series: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(ln(n))^b}{n^a}$$

a) converge
b) diverge

Comment: The question is without context; typically on this site we ask for at least your thoughts on the problem, as well as the source of the problem, your background, and any other information that might be useful. I've left a brief sketch of a solution to accompany a very brief question. Feel free to update the question or leave comments if there's places you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Brief sketch: $b$ is irrelevant, $a > 1$ is necessary trivially since otherwise you have divergence by comparison to $p$-series. This is also sufficient:

$$\frac{\ln(n)^b}{n^{1+\epsilon}} = \bigg(\frac{\ln(n)}{n^{\epsilon/2b}} \bigg)^b \ \frac{1}{n^{1+ \epsilon/2}}$$

and we know that $\ln$ loses to any power, so the first term's contribution is negligible, and the second is summable.

Comment: No, $b$ is not irrelevant and $a>1$ is not necessary if we start the summation at $n=2.$ For example,

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(\ln n)^b}{n}<\infty$$

if $b<-1.$